# Suggestion for cheap but good domain-registrar for com, org or net?

Tags: domain-registration, domain-registrar, recommendations

Does anybody have recommendations for good - but cheap - domain-registrars for the com, org or net domain?  I'm not after hosting, just registering a few domain-names (unless there's a *really* good package-deal).  Lower prices when registering multiple domains would be a plus.  I'm after good personal experiences here...

PS: I am going to use the domain, either host them myself or get a web-hotel later... it's not just to register and park indefinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a suggestion, you might want to do a search on retailmenot.com  .  I was able to get $3.95/month hosting with BlueHost (I know not what your looking for, but though to point it out) with a free domain registration as well.

Comment: Why was I downvoted for this?  ->  They provided a domain registration service practically bundled in with hosting...